# How to extract corresponding value from python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, sharp

I wrote simple python which gives idea how the system performs but the total is not calculated. Now what I want is get the corresponding value (i.e. cone type, Scoop flavor for each scoop, and Topping flavor for each topping) and calculate total cost and finally displaying the items chosen in details (item-->price and quantity) and the total sum.

```
customername = input("Enter the customer's name....")
ic_no = int(input("Enter the number of ice-creams you want to buy"))
total = {}
for i in range(1, ic_no + 1):
    print("For item ", i)
    cone = int(input("Enter the cone type: "))
    scoop = int(input("Enter the scoop amount: "))
    for j in range(1, scoop+1):
        #select flavor type for each scoop
        flavor = int(input("Entr No."+ str(j) +" flavor")) 
    topping = int(input("Entr the toppings amount: "))
    for k in range(1, topping+1):
        #select flavor type for each topping
        top_flavor = int(input("Entr No." + str(k) +" topping flavor"))

print("Total price is ", total)
```

I want to get the selected items simply  by passing number.  For eg: 1 for 'plain' cone type.

```
cone_type = (
    {"name": "Plain",     "price": 2},
    {"name": "Wafle",     "price": 3},
)
scoop_flavor = (
    {"name": "Mint",        "price": 1},
    {"name": "Caramel",     "price": 1},
    {"name": "Chocolate",   "price": 1},
    {"name": "Apple",       "price": 1},
)

topping_flavor = (
    {"name": "Chocolate",         "price": 1},
    {"name": "Caramel",           "price": 0.5},
    {"name": "Peanut",            "price": 0.5},
    {"name": "Coconut Sprinkle",  "price": 0.25},
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter the tuple to get the (only) valid entry, and get its price

```
def get_price(cone_types, cone_name):
    return [cone['price'] for cone in cone_types if cone['name']==cone_name][0]
```

However, if you only have name & price, it would probably be better to directly form you dictionary as

```
 cone_types {'plain': 2, 'wafle': 3}
```

and similarly for other dicts. That's how dictionaries are meant to be used, the key should have discriminative value.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to blue_note answer and would suggest to use Enum to get the cone_type as below:

```
  class ConeType (enum.Enum):
        PLAIN = 1
        WAFLE = 2

print(ConeType(1).name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your inventory data-structures to be a dictionaries of int:list-of-details, instead of your current lists of dictionaries.

For example:

```
cone_type = {1:["Plain", 2], 2:["Waffle", 3]}
```

For the plain cone, the name is accessed with `cone_type[1][0]`, and the price with `cone_type[1][1]`.

You might also consider creating a class each for cones, flavors and toppings. Then, you can use these as values for the dictionaries, in place of lists. Doing so would allow you to access product information as `cone_type[1].getName()` and `cone_type[1].getPrice()`, which is a lot easier to read!